# Can you toggle more than one useState component inside a function in react?

Tags: reactjs

So basically I am trying to render map of restaurant cards. However in the **div** with the **classname= {isExpanded .....**   I would like the text to be cropped and have a **read more** link. When clicked it should show the full text of **data.description** wrapped in the **ReadMore** function and expand the **div** using the class names to fit the entire content.
The problem is if i leave **setIsReadMore** in the **toggleReadMore** on its own it shows the full text when clicked but obviously the text leaks out of the **div**. When i add the **isExpanded** to the **toggleReadMore** it only now alters the size of the **div** on click but doesnt show the full text. I have tried to console log both values before and after and only the **IsExpanded** changes from **true** and **false** but **isreadmore** remains always **true**. Is there a workaround for this? thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import useFetch from '../useFetch.js';
import {RestaurantBox} from '../styles/bestratedrestaurants.js'
import {Image,NameBox, TopBox, P, P2,BottomBox}  from "../styles/reviewsmap.js"
import TestPic from "../assets/london-restaurant.jpeg";
import {Bio,Box,Span} from "../styles/usersMap.js"
import {useState} from 'react';
import '../styles/usermap.css'



const UsersMap = () => {
    const {data,isPending, error} = useFetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/api/users/list/'); //custom hook to fetch data
    const [isExpanded,setIsExpanded] = useState(true)

    const ReadMore = ({ children }) => {
        const text = children;
        const [isReadMore, setIsReadMore] = useState(true);
        const toggleReadMore = () => {
            console.log(isReadMore)
            console.log(isExpanded)
            setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)
            setIsReadMore(!isReadMore)
            console.log(isReadMore)
            console.log(isExpanded)
        };
        return (
            <p className="text">
            {isReadMore ? text.slice(0, 150) : text}
            <Span onClick={toggleReadMore}>
                {isReadMore ? "...read more" : " show less"}
            </Span>
        </p>
        );
    };
    return ( 
        
        <RestaurantBox>
        {error && <div>{error}</div>}
        {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
        {data && data.map(data => (
            <div className={ isExpanded ? 'expand': 'users' }key={data.id}>
                <TopBox>
                    <Image src={TestPic}></Image>
                    <NameBox>
                        <P>{data.first_name} {data.last_name[0]}.</P>
                        {<P2>6 Reviews in total</P2>}
                    </NameBox>
                </TopBox>
                <BottomBox>
                    <Bio>
                        <ReadMore>
                            {data.description}
                        </ReadMore>
                    </Bio>
                </BottomBox>
            </div>
        ))}
    </RestaurantBox>
    );
}

export default UsersMap
```

```
.users {
margin-top:20px;
width:18%;
height:25%;
min-height:300px;
min-width:300px;
border-radius:3px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius:3px;
border-top:5px solid #E47D31;
margin-bottom:25px;
}

.expand{
    margin-top:20px;
width:18%;
height:25%;
border-radius:3px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius:3px;
border-top:5px solid #E47D31;
margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move `const [isReadMore, setIsReadMore] = useState(true);` outside your `ReadMore` function. React needs that in order to know how to change state and preserve it on re-renders.